# Could not find QHash class in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to **import QHash class from PyQt5.QtCore** but no luck.
I got an error

> AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtCore' has no attribute 'QHash'

Could anyone know how to do it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: PyQt5 does not include redundant classes like `QHash`, `QList`, `QString`, etc. Just use a normal python `dict`, `list`, `str`, etc.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much guys.